# Can we block ipod 4th gen users from seeing our app?

Tags: ios, app-store

I've developed a web app for ios. It runs in a UIWebView within a native app shell (similar to the way phone gap works).

On ipod 4th generation, the performance is not only extremely slow, but it seems onTouch events are not always handled correctly (seems like touch moves are dropped somehow).

It runs perfectly well on iphone 4s +/ipad/ipad mini.

I can only guess that 4th gen ipods have implemented UIWebView differently somehow.

Is there a way to hide the app from those users in the app store? The performance is so bad I'd rather not let them use the app.

Thanks

[also I hope the 5th gen ipods are better for UIWebView performance, going to try getting one tomorrow to see]

----- Follow up ---------
The 4th gen ipod actually works fine, I had a foolish bug which wasn't treating ipod devices as touch devices from the perspective of the html layer. Therefore javascript touch events weren't being used, instead click events were being used, which perform really poorly:
https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons

Comment: Which iPad version did you test on?  If it is not the iPad 1, then all the devices you tested are dual core, except for the iPod touch 4 which is single core.  This leads to a very natural increase in performance through GCD.  I doubt that they would change a UIWebView specific to the device, since the specs are almost identical between counterparts (minus cellular radio, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to selectively hide users to people with specific devices this way. As of now, the App Store will only hide iPad apps from iPhone/iPod Touch devices **when those devices are browsing from within their respective App Store app**, but nothing more. Additionally, anyone can browse all App Store apps from iTunes, purchase/download and install to their device(s) at a later time.

Answer (score 1):

The only idea I know to disable some devices for your app in store is to set specific UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities keys. According to [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/B_DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html) matrix there are 3 differences between ipods 4th and 5th gen:

1. auto-focus-camera
2. bluetooth-le
3. camera-flash

But if you set requirements for bluetooth you will exclude ipad 1, ipad 2 and iphone 3gs and 4. If you choose camera flash you will exclude all ipads. Auto-focus-camera seems to be the best option because you are excluding only ipad 1 and 2 gen.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you could hide your app from an iPod/iPhone user if your app is designed for them. You just need to put a disclaimer that your app is sluggish when running to a 4th gen iPod. But other than that, it works pretty well.